# Easy way to force a Sidekiq job into the Retry queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm playing around with (some other things) and need to get some Sidekiq jobs in the Retry queue.

I can't deploy new code with code that intentionally raises an exception to the production environment. Our app is *so* shiny and clean that we *never* have jobs fail in real life. [/sarcasm]

So, is there an easy way to get a job to fail when you can't change code on a staging server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to rails console...

Find a Worker class in your app that does a Model.find(id), where id is a parameter to `perform()`. Chances are many/most of your workers would fit the bill. Maybe something like this:

```
class WidgetSlapWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    Widget.find(id).slap
  end
end
```

From rails console, just queue up a job with a non-existent ID:

```
WidgetSlapWorker.perform_asycnc(-999)
```

That job will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` 'til the cows come home.

If you don't have rails console access, perhaps your app's API has an endpoint with a similar behavior, queueing up a job with a bad ID. If so, use it...then fix that endpoint to do a better job of validating input!

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler...just omit the parameters to *any* worker that accepts args (e.g. `WidgetSlapWorker.perform_async()`) , and you'll get `ArgumentError` errors showing up in the Retry queue.